# Quantidade de determinado caracter contido em uma StringBuilder

Tags: c#, .net

Tenho uma StringBuilder com estes valores: 12**********3*4*.

Existe uma maneira simples de retornar a quantidade de asteriscos sem ter que efetuar um for em cima da minha StringBuilder?

Estou utilizando C# com Net Framework 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma solução possível:

```
StringBuilder valor = new StringBuilder("12**********3*4*");
int total = valor.Length - valor.Replace("*", "").Length;
```

Vale lembrar que qualquer método utilizado vai ter de procurar o caractere dentro da string, similar à uma iteração. Devido a otimizações internas, alguns métodos podem ser mais rápidos que outros. A única maneira de verificar isso é testando e comparando cada um dos métodos. Em geral, a complexidade mínima para esse tipo de operação vai ser **O(n)**, onde n é o tamanho da string.

Comment: Não precisa de passar para String: `StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("12**********3*4*"); int total = builder.Length - builder.Replace("*", "").Length;`

Comment: Verdade Pedro, alterei conforme sua sugestão.

Comment: Acredito que exista um problema nessa resposta, pois quando você chama o método builder.Replace() você está alterando o texto do builder, e na minha opinião uma operação de consulta nunca deve modificar o conteúdo do que está sendo consultado, pois caso contrário o resultado da consulta não vai mais representar a realidade ou estado original dos dados que foram consultados. Neste caso específico, por exemplo, depois da operação você vai saber quantos asterísticos o builder TINHA, porém depois da operação o builder já não vai mais possuir nenhum asterístico.

Comment: Oi @UlyssesAlves, acho seu comentário válido, mas isso vai depender inteiramente da forma como o código vai ser utilizado. Provavelmente, a string "12**********3*4*" venha de outro local, e assim não será alterada com a chamada do Replace no objeto StringBuilder. Se for a string original, algo improvável, basta chamar o método ToString antes de chamar o método Replace.

Answer (score 5):

Usando Linq você pode obter a quantidade de caracteres que são asterísticos da seguinte maneira:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("12**********3*4*");

// É necessário usar ToString() para evitar chamar métodos que alteram o conteúdo do
// StringBuilder durante o processo de contagem dos caracteres, pois caso contrário
// isso poderia ter efeitos colaterais inesperados.
int totalDeAsteristicos = builder.ToString().Count(x => x =='*');
```

Comment: +1, acho esta maneira muito mais legivel.

Comment: Obrigado, @dcastro Além de mais legível, esta forma não modifica o conteúdo do builder. A resposta marcada como aceita pode trazer efeitos colaterais indesejados, alterando totalmente o conteúdo do builder apenas para obter a quantidade de determinado caractere.